# Can't remove an item from listbox excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to fill a listbox in Excel VBA and then after select some itens exclude then from the list. But I keep getting the error '-2147467259 (80004005)'.

I code the following:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ListBox1.ColumnCount = 1
ListBox1.RowSource = "Planilha1!B3:B11"
ListBox1.Font.Size = 10
ListBox1.Font.Name = "Verdana"

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        ListBox1.RemoveItem (i)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It's a rowsource, so it cant be changed i think?

Comment: There's no direct approach - you'll have to decide yourself: either binding to a `RowSource` or flexibilize the listbox contents by separating them from your row source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could swap `.RowSource` for `.List`. The `.List` property accepts 2D arrays of values. So you could load the values in with `.List = Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("B3:B11").Value`. And then `RemoveItem` will work.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ListBox1.ColumnCount = 1
ListBox1.List = Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("B3:B11").Value
ListBox1.Font.Size = 10
ListBox1.Font.Name = "Verdana"

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        ListBox1.RemoveItem (i)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the Range values to the ListBox1's list will allow you to remove items from the ListBox1.

### Demo

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ListBox1
        .List = wsPlanilha1.Range("Planilha1!B3:B11").Value
        .ColumnCount = 1
        .Font.Size = 10
        .Font.Name = "Verdana"
        
        .RemoveItem 4
        .RemoveItem 2
    End With
End Sub

Function wsPlanilha1() As Worksheet
    Set wsPlanilha1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1")
End Function
```

### Result

[image: Demo]

Comment: Ah, you beat me by 1 minute. Interesting idea with the worksheet function, but why separate it like that? Is there a benefit?

Comment: @Toddleson the main reason is it is easier that explaining code names.   I also have a personal macro to creates a module with all a function for each worksheet.  If I pickup someone else's project I don't have to modify there structure.